# How to handle collision when using sprites in a 3d environment in Unity?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, sprites, rts

In games like AoE2, they've used sprites for the buildings and they've handled the collisions very well. How would I achieve something like that in Unity?

Currently, I've tried using box colliders along with the sprite renderer in a child game object. It didn't worked out well though.

Comment: I think those games use a 3 dimensional world, but render it with 2 dimensional tiles

Comment: 2 dimensional tiles? Meaning?

Comment: They aren't models, they are just sprites basically

Comment: Right now, we're doing the sprite thing. Just need to figure out how to handle collisions, and pathfinding when using the sprites.

Comment: @HaikalIzzuddin if gameplay and collisions are handled in 3D space then colliders should be 3D. That is it. I guess 2D colliders don't collide with 3D in Unity. So the answer is obvious. What was your issue with using Box collider?

Comment: It would either be too big for the sprite or too small.

Comment: It's important to explain *in what specific ways* a previous solution attempt "didn't work well" ― this information can give vital clues about what the root problems are and how they could be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after doing much research and tests, we came up with a solution.

[image: Custom solution]

We've used the same 3d mesh but with the mesh renderer turned off. Overlaying the sprite over the mesh, we've managed to come up with something decent.

The mesh would then work as the collider but without the extra high poly cost. So now, interactions could work perfectly.

Comment: If this worked for you, don't forget to come back & mark the answer "Accepted"